# .Net Core Unit Test (xunit) - Handling database

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

So I have a couple of unit test that read or write to an MySql database. I first used `new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>().UseInMemoryDatabase` to have a database created in memory. That worked perfectly.

However, I needed some [MySQL Json columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) and the `InMemoryDatabase` does not support those (for example: `public System.JsonObject<object> EventData { get; set; }`). As they seems to be MySQL specific.

So I thought, I need to test on a real MySQL database but I'm having some trouble with it.

When I create the context I create a new database in the MySQL and push the Migrations to it. That works fine:

```
//First create the schema
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
      .UseMySql(config["ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString"])
      .Options;
_context = new MyContext(options);
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE SCHEMA `MySchema`");


//Use the database
options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
     .UseMySql(config["ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString"] + ";database=MySchema")
     .Options;
_context = new MyContext(options);

//Add migrations
_context.Database.Migrate();
```

The problem is:

- When I run multiple tests at once, the database is created for every test again. While they are being executed asynchronical errors apear because all running tests want to create the same database at the same time. Also, because some unit test populate the tables with some test data (where some tests share the same data, like users with same id), things are messing up.

So I could create a random unique database name for every test but I doubt if that is the way to go.

Also, How do I cleanup after all tests have finished? I could use the context dispose method for that if I would go for the unique database name option. But is that how it should be done?

Comment: Probably what you want is to setup database only once and clean database before every test and make sure that tests are executed orderly. This is a trade off choice you need to do when working with integration tests (external dependencies)

Comment: Thanks, yes I decided that it was not worth it and changed the column to text instead of JSON.